# Нужно ли использовать Command в MediatR для случаев не изменяющих данные в БД

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mediatr

Есть проект (Asp net core) который стараемся поддерживать по DDD Шаблону, Связующим звеном используем библиотеку MediatR. Основной функционал для связи слоев приложения(Query, Command, DomainEvent) через MediatR хорошо реализуется.
Возникла задача Запускать/Останавливать легковесный сервис, который работает на фоне в памяти и сам сервис никак не меняет модель (Entities) и соответственно не комитит изменения в бд.

Возникает желание внедрять сервис, как зависимость, напрямую в контроллер, не используя MediatR.
Можно GetStatistic метод переписать на Query, для возврата статистики работы сервиса и SubscrubeByFlow/UnsubscrubeByFlow как Command с возвратом результата выполнения?
Если кратко еще раз вопрос: нужно ли использовать MediatR для функционала не являющегося частью WriteModel, не изменяющего состояние Entities?

```
[ApiController]
[Route("Api/[controller]")]
public class DataFlowRuntimeControllerBase : ControllerBaseWithErrorHandler
{
    private readonly DataFlowRuntimeService _service;
    

    public DataFlowRuntimeControllerBase(DataFlowRuntimeService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    [HttpGet("GetStatistic")]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<DataFlow>> GetStatistic(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var allFlowsRes = _service.GetAllFlows();
        return CreateHttpResult(allFlowsRes);
    }


    [HttpPut("SubscrubeByFlow/{time}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<DataProviderId>> SubscrubeByFlow([FromBody]DataProviderIdDto id, int time, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var  awaitDataFlowTimeout= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time);
        var dataProviderIdRes = DataProviderId.Create(id.Key, id.Name);
        var result = await dataProviderIdRes.Bind( providerId => _service.SubscribeByFlowAsync(providerId, awaitDataFlowTimeout));  
        return CreateHttpResult(result);
    }


    [HttpPut("UnsubscrubeByFlow")]
    public IActionResult UnsubscrubeByFlow([FromBody]DataProviderIdDto id, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var dataProviderIdRes = DataProviderId.Create(id.Key, id.Name);
        var result =  dataProviderIdRes.Bind(providerId => _service.UnsubscribeByFlow(providerId)); 
        return CreateHttpResult(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Кто и зачем собирается  запускать/останавливать этот сервис и на что это влияет в доменной области? На первый взгляд вообще выглядит как какой-то инфраструктурный сервис, не имеющий отношения к домену приложения и выполняющего какую-то вспомогательную функцию.

Comment: Сервис манипулирует уже созданными и загруженными из БД объектами домена, не меня их состояние, также этот поток данных потом публикуется на Channel<T>. Запускать/Останавливать этот сервис будет пользователь (инженер). Да скорее это инфраструктурный сервис, с помощью объектов домена обрабатывается сторонний поток данных.

Comment: Я не буду писать в поле ответ, т.к. вопрос хоть и неплохой, но opinion based, но из своего опыта ([тынц1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A213987+%5Bmediatr%5D), [тынц2](https://github.com/akmetainfo/WallyBackend)) скажу, что я инфраструктурные сервисы не делаю через Mediatr, у меня он используется на уровне Application для работы с базой. Поэтому на практике - не стоит делать Mediatr, в данном случае это лишняя прослойка абстракции, не особо нужная.

Comment: Спасибо, я также думаю, просто когда все взаимодействие через Mediatr сделано, то начинаешь думать что лучше делать однообразно все, пусть и лишние прослойки или все таки другой подход. Тут я также думаю, что Command  стоит приберечь только для транзакционных изменений домена.